# Sequencing of tasks

Tags: ios, swift

I want a task to be completed and then perform a Segue and to go to a new page. But for some reason it does not perform the Segue and it prints "I AM HERE NOW" before "DOWNLOAD DONE".

```
class DownloadStocksVC: UIViewController {

    var stocks = [Stock]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("stocks").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                self.stocks = []
                for snap in snapshot {

                    if let stockDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let symbol = snap.key
                        let stock = Stock(stockKey: symbol, dictionary: stockDict)
                        self.stocks.append(stock)

                    }
                }
            }
            print("DOWNLOAD DONE")
        })

        print("I AM HERE NOW")
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goFromDownloadToTable", sender: nil)

    }
```

Comment: why don't you perform after "Download Done"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform the segue after the download completes, not before.

Move your call to `performSegue` to the end of the completion block. You also need to run on the main queue.

```
class DownloadStocksVC: UIViewController {
    var stocks = [Stock]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("stocks").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value)

            if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                self.stocks = []
                for snap in snapshot {
                    if let stockDict = snap.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                        let symbol = snap.key
                        let stock = Stock(stockKey: symbol, dictionary: stockDict)
                        self.stocks.append(stock)

                    }
                }
            }

            print("DOWNLOAD DONE")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goFromDownloadToTable", sender: nil)
            }
        })
    }
```